# Javascript string sorting functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

Hello I'm new to JavaScript and I'd like to know whether there are some sorting functions for working with strings since I haven't found any. Perhaps for alphabetical sorting like

```
var str = sort("bca");//str contains "abc"
```

If there aren't any do I have to just make my own or is there any other solution like importing them somehow?

Comment: There are ***tons*** of string functions. I have no idea how you've managed to find none.

Comment: --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 3):

Split the string, sort it and join it,.

```js
var str = sort("bca"); //str contains "abc"

function sort(s) {
  return s
    .split('') // split the string to individual char array
    .sort() // sort it
    .join('') // join it again
    // or use `localeCompare` to avoid different behavior in different browser 
    // return s.split('').sort(function((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join('')  
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

this help you :

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var str = "bca";
            var arr = str.split('');
            alert(arr.sort().join(''));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this syntax.

Try :

```
var myArray = ["frodo", "bilbo", "sam"];
myArrray.sort(); // ["bilbo", "frodo", "sam"]
```

sort() is your precious. Explore it to find your solution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort